# css & html :checked property

Tags: html, css, checkbox

CSS:

```
nav a{
    display: none;
}


#menubutton:checked, nav a{
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <a href="#" id="closenav"><img src="pictures/close.png" alt="Close"  height="20" width="20"></a>
    <a class="navitem" id="firstnavitem" href="index.php">Home</a>
    <a class="navitem" href="#">Test</a>
    <a class="navitem" href="#">Test</a>
    <a class="navitem" href="#">Test</a>
</nav>
```

I want that the HTML code isn't displayed until the `#menubutton` is `:checked`.
(The #menubutton is an invisible checkbox).

If the `#menubutton` is `:checked` I want, that the HTML code is displayed. The code that should be displayed is in the css "nav a{}".

Comment: Check out: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_target

Comment: Also show the `#menubutton` in your HTML context.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think a `,` would be useful there. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#grouping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the *[adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)* `+`.

```css
#menubutton {
  display: none;
}

nav * {
  display: none;
}


#menubutton:checked + nav * {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#closeMenu {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<label for="menubutton">MenuButton</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="menubutton" />
<nav>
    <label for="menubutton"><img src="pictures/close.png" alt="close menu" id="closeMenu" /></label>
    <a class="navitem" id="firstnavitem" href="index.php">Home</a>
    <a class="navitem" href="#">Test</a>
    <a class="navitem" href="#">Test</a>
    <a class="navitem" href="#">Test</a>
</nav>
```

If there are other elements in between your `#menubutton` and your `nav` element, you might need to make use of the *[general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)* `~` instead.

Comment: It will work with both the [`+` adjascent sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) and the [`~` general sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) selectors. Very cool indeed.

Answer (score 1):

css

```
input[type=checkbox] + label {
  color: #ccc;
  font-style: italic;
} 
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  color: #f00;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

html

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ossm" name="ossm"> 
<label for="ossm">CSS is Awesome</label>
```

Comment: Yes, this is the right technique. No, it does not answer the question.

Comment: yes i know, but you can just modify this "nav" instead of "label" :)

Answer (score 1):

This works with pure CSS and HTML using the `:target` psuedo class. It works as of IE 9. [See MSDN for more info.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target)

**Watch out**: the `:target` psuedo-class relies on the *fragment* (or hash) of the current URL, so it might mess up internal page navigation.

```css
#menu {
  display: none;
}

#menu:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#menu">Menu</a>
<nav id="menu">
    <a href="#">Close</a> | 
    <a class="navitem" id="firstnavitem" href="index.php">Home</a> | 
    <a class="navitem" href="#">Test</a> | 
    <a class="navitem" href="#">Test</a> | 
    <a class="navitem" href="#">Test</a>
</nav>
```